# GifSequenceWriter Creating White Gif

Tags: java, gif

I need to split an image into separate slides and compile them into a .gif, but the .gif ends up being plain white. Each slide is 32x32 pixels and they are stacked horizontally with no spaces between them. I used the class [GifSequenceWriter](http://elliot.kroo.net/software/java/GifSequenceWriter/GifSequenceWriter.java) with my code:

```
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.IOException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String image = "Image.png";
    BufferedImage entireSelection = ImageIO.read(new File(image));

    int numOfSlides = entireSelection.getHeight()/32;
    BufferedImage[] slides = new BufferedImage[numOfSlides];

    for(int i = 0; i<numOfSlides; i++){
        slides[i] = entireSelection.getSubimage(0,i*32, 32, 32);

    }

    createGif(slides);
}

private static void createGif(BufferedImage[] slides) throws IOException {
    ImageOutputStream output = new FileImageOutputStream(new File("FinalGif.gif")); 
        GifSequenceWriter writer = new GifSequenceWriter(output, slides[0].getType() ,1,false);

        for (BufferedImage slide : slides) {
            writer.writeToSequence(slide);
        }
        writer.close();
        output.close();
}
```

I have read on how to use the `Writer` and I cannot figure out what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was using a .png that had partial transparency which made everything completely transparent. I just removed the transparency which fixed everything